# JSON image viewer not working on live Firefox, works locally, other browsers, ect.

Tags: jquery, json, image, firefox, getjson

I have tried to find out why JSON is not working in Firefox all over this forum and the internet. It works on tablets, ie, safari. It works on my desktop in Firefox but no after it was live. I've tried a few things (commented out), such as mimeType with no solution. I have tried using the $.ajax with no better luck. Firefox had no javascript errors. I'm using jQuery 1.7.

Console.log is printing out the data. The div introCon is empty (only on firefox).

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  jQuery.support.cors = true;
  //$.ajaxSetup({ mimeType: "application/json" });
  /*$.ajaxSetup({ scriptCharset: "utf-8" , contentType: "application/json;   charset=utf-8"}); */

  // loading pictures
  $.getJSON("intro.json?format=json", function(data){
    var links = '';
    var imageload = '';
    var title = '';

    console.log(data);
    $.each(data, function(key, item) {
      links += ' <a href=' + item.image + '>' + key + '</a>';
      imageload += '<img src="' + item.image + ' " />';
      title += item.alt;
    });

    $('.introCon').html(imageload);
    $('.introCon img').hide();
    $('.introCon img:last').fadeIn(500);
    $('.introCon img').fadeIn(1000);

    rotatePics(2);
  });
});

function rotatePics(currentPhoto) {
  var numberOfPhotos = $('.introCon img').length;
  currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;
  $('.introCon img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut( function() {
    // re-order the z-index
    $('.introCon img').each(function(i) {
      $(this).css(
        'zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos
      );
    });
    $(this).show();
    setTimeout(function() {rotatePics(++currentPhoto);}, 3000);
  });
}
```

Here is the simple JSON from a separate file.

```
{
  "1" : {
    "image" : "portfolio/chrpic.png",
    "alt"   : "Blah.",
    "detail": "Quartz"},
  "2" : {
    "image" : "portfolio/mysspic.png",
    "alt"   : "Landing page.",
    "detail": "Container"},
  "3" : {
    "image" : "portfolio/decode-pic3.png",
    "alt"   : "Decode this.",
    "detail": "Landing page 2"},
  "4" : {
    "image" : "portfolio/simple-think-pic.png",
    "alt"   : "Simple Think",
    "detail": "simpilify your life"}
}
```

Comment: Just looking at the JavaScript it looks like you are building a string called `links` but it doesn't look like you are doing anything with it.  If console.log is showing the `data` then the `getJSON()` succeeded, and you should focus on the rendering

Comment: I removed the bottom function. I could add it back in for this.

Comment: The bottom function is added back. The perimeter data prints to the console log but the source in firebug shows no picture population. The div  introCon is empty. Thanks, I really appreciate your response.

Comment: Is there a reason why the JSON isn't an array `[]`?

Comment: @Jason Sperske: it shouldn't be an array. It's still a valid JSON

Comment: I'll try that. It could be. I've seen it written both ways.

Comment: @jarga: actually you cannot just change `{}` to `[ ]` and expect it to work

Comment: Well it's a valid object literal, but if you are going to $.each() over it doesn't it need to be an array of object literals?

Comment: @Jason Sperske: `$.each()` may iterate over objects as well.

Comment: I should just assume that [John Resig](http://ejohn.org/) is always smarter than me :)

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
  $.each(data, function(key, obj){   
       $.each(obj, function(k, item){  
           links += ' <a href=' + item.image + '>' + key + '</a>';
          imageload += '<img src="' + item.image + ' " />';
           title += item.alt;
        });
  });
```

Comment: I appreciate your answer. Unfortunately, it doesn't work at all. The only problem is with live Firefox. It works perfectly now with files from the desktop on Firefox. I think something is missing in the getJSON area. Maybe making the JSON into a string? MimeType?

Answer (score 0):

OK I've been working on this problem and I think I have a solution (I've stripped the JSON part in the [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/A34Ne/5/), but I think you can see how it would fit back in).  Here is what I've come up with so far:

```
var data = {
    "1": {
        "image": "http://placekitten.com/200/300",
        "alt": "Blah.",
        "detail": "Quartz"
    },

    "2": {
        "image": "http://placekitten.com/g/210/300",
        "alt": "Landing page.",
        "detail": "Container"
    },

    "3": {
        "image": "http://placekitten.com/200/320",
        "alt": "Decode this.",
        "detail": "Landing page 2"
    },

    "4": {
        "image": "http://placekitten.com/g/210/320",
        "alt": "Simple Think",
        "detail": "simpilify your life"
    }
};
var images = [];

$.each(data, function(key, item) {
    images.push('<img src="' + item.image + '" alt="' + item.alt + '"/>')
});

$('.introCon').html(images.join(''));
$('.introCon img').hide();
$('.introCon img:last').fadeIn(500);

rotatePics(2);

function rotatePics(currentPhoto) {
    var numberOfPhotos = $('.introCon img').length;
    currentPhoto = currentPhoto % numberOfPhotos;
    $('.introCon img').eq(currentPhoto).fadeOut(function() {
        // re-order the z-index
        $('.introCon img').each(function(i) {
            $(this).css('zIndex', ((numberOfPhotos - i) + currentPhoto) % numberOfPhotos);
        });
        $(this).show();
        setTimeout(function() {
            rotatePics(++currentPhoto);
        }, 3000);
    });
}
```

Looking at the code it's actually a little tricky to figure out what you are experiencing.  The getJSON looks good (the cors part is unnecessary, unless your service is on a different domain, but with the `console.log(data);` that rules out the possibility that you are having trouble getting the data.  The $.each() call is correct (I was wrong in asking if it could be an array), but there was some odd code in building the list of images.  I've simplified it to a single variable with the `Array.push()` method of string concatenation (faster but honestly at this scale probably not a bottleneck.  Then there was an extra `$('.introCon img').fadeIn(1000);` which was causing all images to fade back in.  I think there must be some CSS to place all of these images on top of each other which I implemented as `img { position: absolute; }`.  If the images are all the same size (or sized though CSS) then this should work, in my case because I'm using the excellent [{placekitten}](http://placekitten.com/) service, I had to give the images different sized to get different pictures.